# VBA loop until the last column and increase value in column by 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project where I need to populate the column headings with incremental values (increased by 1) until the Last Column.

The code is working OK but the value in the column headings is NOT increased by 1. It is just taking the original value and place it over all columns.

Could you help me?

My code so far:

```
Sub LastColumn_PopulateHeadings()

'Declare variable for Last row (Prior FY)
Dim LastColumn As Integer
Dim i As Integer


'Find the last Column used

LastColumn = Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Column

'populate headings with column values UNTIL LAST COLUMN

' Loop to populate the heading until LAST column

i = 8

Do While i < LastColumn
'MsgBox (LastColumn)
    
    Cells(4, i).Value = Cells(4, i).Value + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Code is working for me. Use `=` to `Do While` condition for last column as well `Do While i <= LastColumn`.

Comment: Thanks!!! The loop is working fine. My issue is in increasing the value in the columns. I want to have 1 in column 1, then 2 and 1, then 3 and 3 and so on. Any thoughts how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code a little strange, but probably i am missing something. Anyway this one should work:

```
Sub LastColumn_PopulateHeadings()

'Declare variable for Last row (Prior FY)
Dim LastColumn As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim IntCounter01 As Integer '<<<<<<ADDED LINE (1 of 3)


'Find the last Column used

LastColumn = Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Column

'populate headings with column values UNTIL LAST COLUMN

' Loop to populate the heading until LAST column

i = 8
IntCounter01 = 1 '<<<<<<ADDED LINE (2 of 3)

Do While i < LastColumn
'MsgBox (LastColumn)
    
    Cells(4, i).Value = IntCounter01
    i = i + 1
     IntCounter01 = IntCounter01 + 1 '<<<<<<ADDED LINE (3 of 3)
Loop

End Sub
```

I took your code and added 3 lines. You could also use a For-Next cycle instead of using a Do-While-Loop cycle since you already know your maximal value. Something like:

```
For i = i To LastColumn - 1

    Cells(4, i).Value = IntCounter01
    IntCounter01 = IntCounter01 + 1
    
Next
```

You could also use a formula to cover your range instead of picking each cell one by one. Like this:

```
Sub LastColumn_PopulateHeadings()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim IntFirstColumn As Integer
    Dim IntLastColumn As Integer
    Dim IntRow As Integer
    Dim IntFirstValue
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    
    'Setting variables.
    IntFirstValue = 1
    IntRow = 4
    IntFirstColumn = 8
    IntLastColumn = Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'Setting first value in the first cell.
    Cells(IntRow, IntFirstColumn).Value = IntFirstValue
    
    'Setting RngRange01.
    Set RngRange01 = Range(Cells(IntRow, IntFirstColumn + 1), Cells(IntRow, IntLastColumn - 1))
    
    'Setting formulas in RngRange01.
    RngRange01.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+1"
    
    'Copy-pasting the values in RngRange01.
    RngRange01.Value = RngRange01.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice!!! It's working properly now and the value is increased in every column. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to know. You can mark the answer as accepted then.

Comment: Thanks again!!! I marked your answer as accepted. Have a great day:-)